# How to set the key dynamically based on the index of the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have the situation where the form object data has to be convert to key value pair. The key will have the name based on the index of the iteration. Please help on this. Thanks

```
data = [
  {id: 1001, name: "john"},
  {id: 1002, name: "samanta"}
]

finalArr = []
 
data.forEach((elem, index) => {
  levels[index][base_id]: elem.id,
  levels[index][base_name]: elem.name,
  finalArr.push({...above...})
});


expected output
[
  {levels[0][base_id]: 1001, levels[0][base_name]: "john"},
  {levels[1][base_id]: 1002, levels[1][base_name]: "samanta"}
]
```

[image]

Comment: What is base_id and base_name it's not declared in your snippet.

Comment: it's just a string. only the index is dynamic based on the iteration index

Comment: Answered with snippet try now.

Comment: Cover string literals with []. I have updated answer. You can try here too https://jsbin.com/nisasex/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This will preserve the index of the item in the original array while letting you change the item's keys/properties.

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1001, name: "john"},
  {id: 1002, name: "samanta"}
]

// this will get you the example output in the question
const out = data.map((item, idx) => {
  return {
    [`levels[${idx}][base_id]`]: item.id,
    [`levels[${idx}][base_name]`]: item.name
  };
});

console.log(out);
```

This will output the following:

```
[
  {
    "levels[0][base_id]": 1001,
    "levels[0][base_name]": "john"
  },
  {
    "levels[1][base_id]": 1002,
    "levels[1][base_name]": "samanta"
  }
]
```

However, I don't think that is actually what you are wanting to do. You are probably trying to do the following:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1001, name: "john"},
  {id: 1002, name: "samanta"}
]

// this will get you what I actually think that you want
const levels = data.map((item, idx) => {
  return {
    base_id: item.id,
    base_name: item.name
  };
});

console.log(levels);

// the difference being that you access the second example like this
levels[0]["base_id"]; // 1001
```

This second example would output the following:

```
[
  {
    "base_id": 1001,
    "base_name": "john"
  },
  {
    "base_id": 1002,
    "base_name": "samanta"
  }
]
```

This lets you access the data like `levels[0]["base_id"]`.

Comment: hey kyle, but the key name should be dynamic and that is based on the index of the iteration. is that possible anyway?

Comment: hey @Sajz are you wanting to access the output like `output[0][base_id]` or are you actually wanting to do `output[0]["levels[0][base_id]"]`?

Comment: hey kyle. only the index is dynamic, rest are normal one.  

`levels[${index}][base_id]`: elem.id,

level base_id are normal string

Comment: @Sajz okay I've updated the answer with what I think you're wanting to actually do. Keep in mind that if the object's property isn't an integer that you need to use `levels[${index]["base_id"]` or `levels[${index}].base_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is base_id and base_name is so i am making as a string for now.

```js
const finalArr = data.map((elem, index) => {
    return {
     [`levels[${index}][base_id]`]: elem.id,
      [`levels[${index}][base_name]`]: elem.name
     }
  });
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help. but this is not working out in react. for some reason using string literals is not accepted. its throwing error

Comment: let finalArr = data.map((elem, index) => {
      return {
        `levels[${index}][base_id]`: elem.id,
      };
    });

Comment: Property assignment expected.
';' expected.
Expression expected.
')' expected.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nisasex/edit i have created a bin which is working.